# How to loop back to the first line after invalid input? Python

Tags: python

I recently started my python course. I want to allow the user input again (back to the first line of question) after getting invalid inputs, therefore I added in the while loop. However, now, when the input is "yes", python prints out "I do not understand". Can I know what is wrong with the code and how should I fix it?

**Here is the code**

```
print('Hi, I am your bot, James!')

while True:
    user_reply=input("Are you ready for today's activity? ")
    if user_reply.lower == 'yes':
        for_calculation()

    elif user_reply.lower() == 'no':
        while True:
            double_confirm=input('Are you sure? ')
            if double_confirm.lower() == 'yes':
                print('See you next time.')
                exit()
            elif double_confirm.lower() == 'no':
                for_calculation()
            else:
                print('I do not understand.')

    else:
        print('I do not understand.')
```

And here's the result

```
Hi, I am your bot, James!
Are you ready for today's activity? yes
I do not understand.
Are you ready for today's activity?
```

Comment: Replace `if user_reply.lower == 'yes':` with `if user_reply.lower() == 'yes':`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `if user_reply.lower == 'yes':` you forgot the `()`:

```py
if user_reply.lower() == 'yes':
```

If you do `user_reply.lower`, you are not getting the lowercase content of `user_reply`, you're getting the *function itself* that gives you the lowercase content. The `()` are very important because they tell Python not to just fetch the function, but to actually call it and give you the result.

Comment: It's a duplicate though.